# jQuery AJAX parsererror

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing, parse-error

I am working on the following page.

http://www.ranger.ryerson.ca/library/test/steveDev/testcarousel/test.html

it works in firefox, chrome, and opera, but in IE6,IE7, and Safari (the god forsaken browsers) they all give me "parsererror"

My page uses the jquery XML parser, and the bad browsers dont like it. The troubled code is the following

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.ranger.ryerson.ca/library/test/steveDev/testcarousel/readXML.cfm",


        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('images').each(function(){
                $(this).find('pic').each(function() {
                    temp= '<a href="'+$(this).find('link').text()+'"><img src="'+$(this).find('thumbnail').text()+'" width="'+$(this).find('width').text()+'" style="border-style: none" height="75" title="'+$(this).find('alt').text()+'"alt="'+$(this).find('alt').text()+'" /></a>';
                    carousel.add(count, temp);
                    count++;
                });
                carousel.size(count);
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        } 

    })
```

how can I resolve my problem

Comment: good luck with jCarousel; that plugin drove me nuts.

Comment: Is this ajax call going to a different domain?  Is so, maybe it's a jsoncallback issue?  Just a guess.

Comment: I got the carousel part working, my problem is parsing some input for it

Comment: This isnt cross domain issues, they are both on the same server, same domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an Encoding Error encountered on this node:

```
<alt>Eugénie</alt>
```

on line 97.

I notice you specify `encoding="utf-8"` as the encoding. Are you sure the `"é"` is really encoded with utf-8?

Comment: never noticed that. How can I escape this character?

Comment: Or... the HTML entity: `&eacute;`, or another way to write the character in Unicode: `U+00E9`. Keep in mind that the HTML entity will make an XML parser unhappy unless it's already been defined (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_entity_references).

Comment: Okay, you are correct about that é being the cause of the compatibility issues. However, I do not have access to change the XML source. Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Figure out what it actually *is* encoded as, and specify that encoding. It might just be Unicode, rather than UTF-8. I did notice that the é is not correctly displayed in the alt text for that album in Firefox.